# 2sxc Dropdown list string don't appear

Tags: 2sxc

I have a problem on a dropdown list, I need to edit it and add some options, but I can't or better I dont' find the string list?
[Click there for see Dropdown list string is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcLEH.png)

Can You help me?

i have other dropdown in this app and the other work well

thanks
Fabio

Answer (score 0):

You are probably affected by an upgrade-issue. 2sxc had to do a change in the field-definition structure when the UI went to angular in 8.0. What happened is this

Previously the entity describing the @String for an input-field had too many properties - many of which never applied to the specific field (like a length-field, which didn't apply to a drop-down).

In 2sxc 8 this was changed, so a string field now has 3 metadata entities describing what the UI should show

1. @All - containing the main properties like name, help text, required
2. @String - not containing anything any more
3. @string-dropdown - containing the settings only relevant to drop-downs

The @String-metadata entity still exists to ensure old UIs still work, but it's deprecated. So the values don't show up any more. But :) you can still get it from debug-mode, to then copy the values to the new container. Here's how:

1. Go to the admin > data UI
2. Go into debug mode (Ctrl+Click) http://2sxc.org/en/Blog/post/debugging-2sxc-8-enter-advanced-mode-with-control-click
3. now open the UI - you should see all hidden fields now